# Dynamic reference to JComponents?

Tags: java, variables, user-interface, dynamic, reference

First Java project - solving a Sudoku puzzle.  Used SDK to create GUI first (bad idea?).  GUI has 9x9 grid of square JButtons.  Added handlers (81!) such that 'click' cycles values '_','1',...'9'.  Named buttons in grid to reflect position (also painful).  To solve puzzle implemented 9x9 array of Tile objects.  Tiles to mirror state of respective JButtons (text value, etc).  Want to use array of Tiles to solve puzzle. To use get/setText methods to r/w from array to/from JButtons.  Hit wall!! Can't find way to reference JButtons.  Hoped to create String representing JButton variable name (easy enough) then magically convert (type casting?) to reference JButton object.  Not possible?  A String is a String is a...?  I have an object in memory (JButton) I can't reference dynamically?  Approaches seen (tic-tac-toe, etc.) create an array of JButtons to access by index.  Don't want to do this as it takes away from simplicity of using swing.  The SDK generated source code is ~2000 lines already!  Use hash to map objects to objects?  Ideally each Tile object will map to respective JButton when created. Hopefully enough detail here to explain what I am 'trying' to do.  Is this case where pointers would be nice?  Is this a downfall of using SDK for GUI?  Shortcoming in Java?  Can anyone recommend approach to this (tricks or tips)?? Thanks!!

Comment: You should use an array of buttons instead of having 81 variables. This will unify your access to the buttons and should greatly reduce your 2000 lines of code. Also, you can use a single ActionHandler and attach it to all buttons: `ActionEvent.getSource()` tells you which button was clicked.

Comment: You *could* create a `Map<String, JButton>`, fill it with `map.put("button00", new JButton())` and access the buttons with `map.get("button00")`. But the description sounds as if there are quite some issues with your approach. When you say that you "used SDK to create GUI", do you mean that you used some GUI-builder where you arrange your components visually (and not by really writing *code*)? This auto-generated code is often horrible and is certainly not the best basis to learn Java....

Comment: I think I tried the universal event handler and ‘this’, or sans, but no compile. I wrote the code so I only had to change the suffix of two variable names each paste (get/set).  That labor aside, it seems I am stuck with the suggestion of an array of JButtons.  Is there a way to reference my array of JButtons via the swing interface (for ease of UI design) or do I now have my own JButton objects the SDK can't access?  The reverse of what I had.  Good grief.  Maybe I'm beginning to appreciate C/C++ more and more.

Answer (score 0):

Array of Objects extending JButton is way to go.  Learned much here and many thanks to all who contributed!!  For newbie to Java to think an extensive swing UI is an easy approach is foolish.  Took me a few weeks to learn basics of JComponents.  I still use 'Window Builder' but only for the most basic interface.  Want to challenge a new student? Let him/her try to tackle Sudoku as first project!  Now that I have conquered this UI I feel on top of the world and no problem is beyond my reach!  THANKS AGAIN!!